# join an array of custom Objects

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I've created a custom object which contain id, name and shortname. I would like to only retrieve the id's and do a `",".join()` so that it will be a string like for instance `"1, 2"`

So how can I convert an array like `var recentArray = Array<News>()` to an string with only the id's seperated by comma?

Custom Class

```
class Team: NSObject{
    var id: Int!
    var name: NSString!
    var shortname: NSString!


    init(id: Int, name:NSString, shortname: NSString) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.shortname = shortname
    }


    required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let id = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("id")
        let name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
        let shortname = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("shortname") as! String
        self.init(id: id, name: name, shortname: shortname)
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeInteger(id, forKey: "id")
        aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name")
        aCoder.encodeObject(shortname, forKey: "shortname")
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why would you use implicitly unwrapped optionals if you're assigning a non-optional value in `init` anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have tu use `map` function.

```
var t1 = Team(id: 1, name: "Adria", shortname: "Ad")
var t2 = Team(id: 2, name: "Roger", shortname: "Ro")
var t3 = Team(id: 3, name: "Raquel", shortname: "Ra")

var array: [Team] = [t1, t2, t3];

var arrayMap: Array = array.map(){ toString($0.id) }
var joinedString: String  = ",".join(arrayMap)

println(joinedString) // 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` the objects to an array of strings, and then join that:

```
", ".join(recentArray.map { toString($0.id) })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the array to get just id's from the Team array and reduce the array to string:

```
let a = Team(id: 1, name: "Greg", shortname: "G") 
let b = Team(id: 2, name: "John", shortname: "J") 
let c = Team(id: 3, name: "Jessie", shortname: "Je") 
let d = Team(id: 4, name: "Ann", shortname: "A")

let array = [a,b,c,d]

let result = array.map({$0.id}).reduce("", combine: {result, id in return result == "" ? "\(id)" : "\(result),\(id)"})
```